# emscripten pure opengl (no sdl2 or glfw3)

Tags: android-ndk, emscripten, multiplatform

I want to make multiplatform application, currently it works with PC and android and I want to port it to web.
I don't want to use sdl2 or glfw3.
All I want is to create opengl context and then just run my opengles code (like in Android one can have a very basic app just by creating `GLSurfaceView` instance and implementing 2 callbacks: `onDraw`, `onCreate` in ndk)

Do you know any text/turorials refering this problem?

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your problem, crosscompiling to emscripten? in cmake scripting?

Comment: I can compile sdl2 to .html/.js without problem, but I would like to do opengl without sdl2 or any other libraries. Just create a context and have fun.

Comment: So do you want to create an opengl context in c++? opengl ES? or opengl 4.0? I think you may have to change your code to implement your sdl2 and glfw3 features in a low level opengl engine.

Did you try to use nehe tutorials? http://nehe.gamedev.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [createContext](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/6dc4ac5f9e4d8484e273e4dcc554f809738cedd6/src/library_browser.js#L270) Module method from the browser to create the WebGL context. After that, simply call your compiled OpenGL code and you're good to go :)